# How to bind in Twitter in my homepage?

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I will use twitter and show it on my page like a news-flash.

I found a lot of Twitter API Demos with updating twitter, but I don't want this, want only read and show in any form I like.

Anyone knows good and easy classes for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use on [my website](http://www.robertgreiner.com).

You can copy and paste this code and add your information.
Also, you can style it any way you wish with CSS.

```
<div id="twitter">
    <ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/cubeantics" id="twitter-link" style="display:block;text-align:right;">follow me on Twitter</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/cubeantics.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=7"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a number of widgets to choose from: http://twitter.com/goodies/widgets